# convert DataFrameGroupBy into data frame so that I can get individual columns

Tags: python, group-by

I have a data set following columns:

> Country
>
> Gdp
>
> Life Satisfaction

I want to group on country and GDP. I want GDP col in a list names X and Life Satisfaction in list Y to create scatter plot.

Using this I am able to group:

```
df=dataSet.groupby(["Country","Gdp Per Capita"])
```

But `df` is `generic.DataFrame.GroupBy`

How can I extend my code to take values in X and Y.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly:

```
df=dataSet.groupby(["Country","Gdp Per Capita"], as_index=False).mean()
X = df['Gdp Per Capita'].to_list()
Y = df['Life Satisfaction'].to_list()
```